# AngularJS ng-repeat and jQuery accordion

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to create an accordion tree menu using AngularJS ng-repeat and jQuery accordion widget.  Here is what I have so far:

HTML

```
<div>
    <div ng-controller="PersonFavoritesController">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in favorites.Folders">
                <div class="folder-toggle">
                    <h3>
                        <i class="fa fa-folder"></i>                                   
                        {{item.FolderLabel}}
                    </h3>
                    <div>
                        {{item.Folders.length}}<br />
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>
            <li ng-repeat="item in favorites.CurrentItems">
                {{item.ItemLabel}}
            </li>
        </ul>             
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $(".folder-toggle").accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            active: false
        });
```

The tree menu displays but it cannot be expanded or collapsed

Answer (score 0):

Update your script

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('ul').on('.folder-toggle',function(){
            $(this).accordion({
               collapsible: true,
                active: false
             });
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a watch to my collection worked for me:

```
$scope.$watch('favorites',function(){
    $(element).accordion();
});
```

I am no angularjs expert, so there's my 2 cents.